# When creating a new env with conda, the command line reports a JSONDecodeError error

Tags: conda

I'm trying to use Conda to create a new env. The new env have been created successfully, but the cmd outputs some error messages.

command:

```
conda create -n learn-pytorch python=3.6
```

error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): / ERROR conda.auxlib.logz:stringify(155): Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3-2020\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "D:\anaconda3-2020\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s))
  File "D:\anaconda3-2020\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "D:\anaconda3-2020\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3-2020\lib\site-packages\conda\auxlib\logz.py", line 149, in stringify
    requests_models_Response_builder(builder, obj)
  File "D:\anaconda3-2020\lib\site-packages\conda\auxlib\logz.py", line 125, in requests_models_Response_builder
    resp = response_object.json()
  File "D:\anaconda3-2020\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
ERROR conda.auxlib.logz:stringify(155): Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3-2020\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "D:\anaconda3-2020\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "D:\anaconda3-2020\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "D:\anaconda3-2020\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

What should I do?